# PHP group multidimensional array to process each group of array independently

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am developing a unique group based cart system that works differently than the traditional cart system. For the cart, I get the rows that contain `group_id`. I want to group all orders by `group_id` and process its data to calculate dynamic pricing, total items, discounts, and many more.

> That data I want to show is for admin use using `datatables`. So I
> cannot run a query with `group_id` filter. I have to display all
> groups data for admin.

I get the query result as below.

### Query Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 14
            [order_number] => 2020111629863
            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
            [product] => 297
            [product_option] => 0
            [qty] => 3
            [group_id] => 298
            [group_admin] => 72
            [group_user] => 63
            [customers] => [{"name":"Roma Patel","email":"roma@pad.com","qty":"1"},{"name":"Manoj Bajpai","email":"manoj@skdf.com","qty":"2"}]
            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
            [added_at] => 2020-12-26 10:39:13
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 15
            [order_number] => 2020111618475
            [group_order_number] => 1605498753184
            [product] => 174
            [product_option] => 0
            [qty] => 1
            [group_id] => 184
            [group_admin] => 71
            [group_user] => 75
            [customers] => [{"name":"Loveena","email":"love@sdklf.com","qty":1}]
            [identifier] => FqPeYG6L2FVMQFGM_990314138546b9b5ce73df287919ca0a
            [added_at] => 2020-11-16 07:52:33
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 16
            [order_number] => 2020111629863
            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
            [product] => 168
            [product_option] => 0
            [qty] => 1
            [group_id] => 298
            [group_admin] => 72
            [group_user] => 63
            [customers] => [{"name":"Roma Patel","email":"roma@pad.com","qty":1}]
            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
            [added_at] => 2020-12-15 12:18:23
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 17
            [order_number] => 2020111629863
            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
            [product] => 64
            [product_option] => 0
            [qty] => 2
            [group_id] => 298
            [group_admin] => 72
            [group_user] => 63
            [customers] => [{"name":"Rinku Patani","email":"rinku@patani.com","qty":"2"}]
            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
            [added_at] => 2020-12-22 12:27:46
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 18
            [order_number] => 2020111629873
            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
            [product] => 64
            [product_option] => 0
            [qty] => 1
            [group_id] => 298
            [group_admin] => 72
            [group_user] => 73
            [customers] => [{"name":"Vijay Sonar","email":"vson@aksd.com","qty":"1"}]
            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
            [added_at] => 2020-12-24 10:51:00
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 19
            [order_number] => 2020111618475
            [group_order_number] => 1605498753184
            [product] => 102
            [product_option] => 0
            [qty] => 1
            [group_id] => 184
            [group_admin] => 71
            [group_user] => 75
            [customers] => [{"name":"Rima Lagu","email":"rima@lagosd.com","qty":1}]
            [identifier] => FqPeYG6L2FVMQFGM_990314138546b9b5ce73df287919ca0a
            [added_at] => 2020-12-24 13:01:14
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
            [order_number] => 2020111629873
            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
            [product] => 146
            [product_option] => 0
            [qty] => 2
            [group_id] => 298
            [group_admin] => 72
            [group_user] => 73
            [customers] => [{"name":"Ramesh Oza","email":"ramesh@amdf.com","qty":"2"}]
            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
            [added_at] => 2020-12-26 10:01:44
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 21
            [order_number] => 2020111629873
            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
            [product] => 297
            [product_option] => 1
            [qty] => 3
            [group_id] => 298
            [group_admin] => 72
            [group_user] => 73
            [customers] => [{"name":"Aniketh Vora","email":"aniket@sdfk.com","qty":"3"}]
            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
            [added_at] => 2020-12-26 10:31:55
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 23
            [order_number] => 2020111629863
            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
            [product] => 146
            [product_option] => 0
            [qty] => 3
            [group_id] => 298
            [group_admin] => 72
            [group_user] => 63
            [customers] => [{"name":"Roma Patel","email":"roma@pad.com","qty":1},{"name":"vijay sonar","email":"vso@lkd.com","qty":2}]
            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
            [added_at] => 2020-12-26 10:48:33
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 24
            [order_number] => 2020111629863
            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
            [product] => 297
            [product_option] => 1
            [qty] => 2
            [group_id] => 298
            [group_admin] => 72
            [group_user] => 63
            [customers] => [{"name": "Harprit Sing", "email": "harpr@sfk.co", "qty": 1}, {"name": "Roma Patel", "email": "roma@pad.com", "qty": 1}]
            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
            [added_at] => 2020-12-26 10:56:34
        )

)
```

I have grouped all items based on the `group_id` as below.

### Grouped items by Group ID

```
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [298] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 14
                            [order_number] => 2020111629863
                            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
                            [product] => 297
                            [product_option] => 0
                            [qty] => 3
                            [group_id] => 298
                            [group_admin] => 72
                            [group_user] => 63
                            [customers] => [{"name":"Roma Patel","email":"roma@pad.com","qty":"1"},{"name":"Manoj Bajpai","email":"manoj@skdf.com","qty":"2"}]
                            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
                            [added_at] => 2020-12-26 10:39:13
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 16
                            [order_number] => 2020111629863
                            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
                            [product] => 168
                            [product_option] => 0
                            [qty] => 1
                            [group_id] => 298
                            [group_admin] => 72
                            [group_user] => 63
                            [customers] => [{"name":"Roma Patel","email":"roma@pad.com","qty":1}]
                            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
                            [added_at] => 2020-12-15 12:18:23
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 17
                            [order_number] => 2020111629863
                            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
                            [product] => 64
                            [product_option] => 0
                            [qty] => 2
                            [group_id] => 298
                            [group_admin] => 72
                            [group_user] => 63
                            [customers] => [{"name":"Rinku Patani","email":"rinku@patani.com","qty":"2"}]
                            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
                            [added_at] => 2020-12-22 12:27:46
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                            [order_number] => 2020111629873
                            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
                            [product] => 64
                            [product_option] => 0
                            [qty] => 1
                            [group_id] => 298
                            [group_admin] => 72
                            [group_user] => 73
                            [customers] => [{"name":"Vijay Sonar","email":"vson@aksd.com","qty":"1"}]
                            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
                            [added_at] => 2020-12-24 10:51:00
                        )

                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 20
                            [order_number] => 2020111629873
                            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
                            [product] => 146
                            [product_option] => 0
                            [qty] => 2
                            [group_id] => 298
                            [group_admin] => 72
                            [group_user] => 73
                            [customers] => [{"name":"Ramesh Oza","email":"ramesh@amdf.com","qty":"2"}]
                            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
                            [added_at] => 2020-12-26 10:01:44
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 21
                            [order_number] => 2020111629873
                            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
                            [product] => 297
                            [product_option] => 1
                            [qty] => 3
                            [group_id] => 298
                            [group_admin] => 72
                            [group_user] => 73
                            [customers] => [{"name":"Aniketh Vora","email":"aniket@sdfk.com","qty":"3"}]
                            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
                            [added_at] => 2020-12-26 10:31:55
                        )

                    [6] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 23
                            [order_number] => 2020111629863
                            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
                            [product] => 146
                            [product_option] => 0
                            [qty] => 3
                            [group_id] => 298
                            [group_admin] => 72
                            [group_user] => 63
                            [customers] => [{"name":"Roma Patel","email":"roma@pad.com","qty":1},{"name":"vijay sonar","email":"vso@lkd.com","qty":2}]
                            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
                            [added_at] => 2020-12-26 10:48:33
                        )

                    [7] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 24
                            [order_number] => 2020111629863
                            [group_order_number] => 1605497369298
                            [product] => 297
                            [product_option] => 1
                            [qty] => 2
                            [group_id] => 298
                            [group_admin] => 72
                            [group_user] => 63
                            [customers] => [{"name": "Harprit Sing", "email": "harpr@sfk.co", "qty": 1}, {"name": "Roma Patel", "email": "roma@pad.com", "qty": 1}]
                            [identifier] => AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352
                            [added_at] => 2020-12-26 10:56:34
                        )

                )

            [184] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 15
                            [order_number] => 2020111618475
                            [group_order_number] => 1605498753184
                            [product] => 174
                            [product_option] => 0
                            [qty] => 1
                            [group_id] => 184
                            [group_admin] => 71
                            [group_user] => 75
                            [customers] => [{"name":"Loveena","email":"love@sdklf.com","qty":1}]
                            [identifier] => FqPeYG6L2FVMQFGM_990314138546b9b5ce73df287919ca0a
                            [added_at] => 2020-11-16 07:52:33
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 19
                            [order_number] => 2020111618475
                            [group_order_number] => 1605498753184
                            [product] => 102
                            [product_option] => 0
                            [qty] => 1
                            [group_id] => 184
                            [group_admin] => 71
                            [group_user] => 75
                            [customers] => [{"name":"Rima Lagu","email":"rima@lagosd.com","qty":1}]
                            [identifier] => FqPeYG6L2FVMQFGM_990314138546b9b5ce73df287919ca0a
                            [added_at] => 2020-12-24 13:01:14
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

### The Problem

I have to do various calculations and process data for each group. For instance, total product counts for the group by calculating each order (row) for the group—total discount for the group.

So here, I want to know how can I process each group (index) separately. As if I run the for-each loop for the grouped array, it runs through all groups at once. And won't get the correct sum.

For Instance,

Calculating the total number of products for the group `298, 184, ...` so on. I have all my methods set to calculate using all the ids in the array.

Please let me know if you need further details or information.

## Updated Info

### DB Table

[image]

### Datatables Column

The end result will display as in below datatable. One row for each group.
[image]

Comment: If you fetch all rows by your query, just do these calculations during your iteration. If not, and you have pagination for example, use additional query with `GROUP BY`

Comment: instead of foreach ($result as $group) use foreach ($result['product'] as $group

Comment: @HTMHell  I want total numbers for the entire group. Not for the individual row. So for instance, if group id 298 has three orders, I need to get total items for three orders for the same group. Same for discount, total amount, etc. How can I calculate and separate the result for each group? As the `datatables` each row will be a one group total data.

Comment: @m47730 the `products` key I have added manually. I have more data that will be assigned to another (siblings) keys.

Comment: Your intentions are not clear enough. Show us a minimal example of database data, and how you want it to be displayed (with all the sums)

Comment: @HTMHell I have updated my question adding a table and datatable (end result) screenshot. The price, bonus, qty all will be calculated dynamically passing the ids. So eventually all items for the group will be counted and displayed as a single row in datatable.

Comment: Then why aren't you using `GROUP BY`? it seems like a prefect fit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, and as suggested by @HTMHell this kind of operations are faster on database.

```
<?php

foreach ($result as $id => $group)
{
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($group as $row)
    {
        $sum += $row['qty']
    }

    echo "group $id total qty: $sum";
}
```